# Inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, ttmath

I am using Qt and want to include the [ttmath library](http://www.ttmath.org/). It tested fine on Windows XP and Windows 7. I use Qt-creator on Ubuntu now and when I try to compile the project it gives me following error:

```
.../ttmathuint_x86.h:637: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an 'asm'
 : "cc", "memory" );
                   ^
```

Part of the code looks like this:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
uint dummy, dummy2;

__asm__  __volatile__(

        "xorl %%edx, %%edx    \n"
        "negl %%eax           \n"  // CF=1 if rax!=0 , CF=0 if rax==0

    "1:                                 \n"
        "movl (%%esi,%%edx,4), %%eax    \n"
        "sbbl %%eax, (%%ebx,%%edx,4)    \n"

        "incl %%edx                     \n"
        "decl %%ecx                     \n"
        "jnz 1b                         \n"

        "adc %%ecx, %%ecx               \n"

    : "=c" (c), "=a" (dummy), "=d" (dummy2)
    : "0" (b),  "1" (c), "b" (p1), "S" (p2)
    : "cc", "memory" );

#endif
```

The error only shows when I add parser to my project like one from the last example, here: http://www.ttmath.org/samples

I have no idea why that doesn't work since I know little about assembly or compilation process.

I read on the internet that the resolution is to add QMAKE_CXXFALGS = -fno-gcse in my ".pro" file but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a 32-bit build?

Comment: Also, exactly which version of compiler are you using in each case?

Comment: Yes it is 32-bit. Based on Qt 5.0.2 (GCC 4.7.3, 32 bit)

Comment: And what compiler are you using under Windows?

Comment: Visual Express 2008 default compiler

Answer (score 4):

The reason for this error is the `-fPIC` or `-fpic` compiler flag which indicates that position independent code should be emitted. To locate variables it uses a global offset table whose pointer is stored in `ebx`. Therefore with this flag you are not allowed to use `ebx` in inline assembly.

According to https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/26/new-optimizations-for-x86-in-upcoming-gcc-50-32bit-pic-mode this is changed in GCC 5.0.
The library probably changes your flags so you have to see if you can change your code.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could solve it updating my gcc to version 5.0

This is the source link https://askubuntu.com/questions/618474/how-to-install-the-latest-gcurrently-5-1-in-ubuntucurrently-14-04 and these are the commands they suggest (and the ones I used):

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5